# Customizing PUT route on save method in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I would like to manually specify a PUT route for saving my model. Is this possible with ember?

For example, I have a conversation model and when I call conversation.save(), I don't want it to search for the PUT conversations/someMail/conversations/:id but to manually tell ember to use PUT /conversations/:id instead.

Here is my namespace :

```
App.ApplicationAdapter.reopen({

namespace: 'conversations/someEmail'

});
```

Router :

```
App.Router.map(function(){

//Routing list to raw namespace path
this.resource('conversations', { path : '/' }, function() {
    this.resource('conversation', { path : '/:conversation_id'});
});

});
```

Model :

```
App.Conversation = DS.Model.extend({

readStatus: DS.attr('string'),
url: DS.attr('string'),
status: DS.attr('string'),
lastMessage: DS.attr('string'),
createdAt: DS.attr('string'),
timeAgoElement: DS.attr('string'),
customer: DS.belongsTo('customer'),
content: DS.attr('array'),

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the URL in the adapter by overriding [buildURL](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_buildURL):

```
App.ApplicationAdapter.reopen({
    buildURL: function(type, id, record, requestType) {
        if (type === 'conversation' && requestType === 'PUT') {
            return '/conversations/' + id;
        }
        return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Its exact signature depends on your ember version so try it out in your app.

Comment: requestType returns undefined. any idea?

Comment: Ember seems to ignore adapter's namespace and tries to use put at the wrong request url. PUT http://dev.rails.local:3000/conversations/maxime.l@kimoby.com 404 (Not Found)

Comment: See if you can upgrade to the latest ember-data. That should give you the `requestType`. You will have to add the namespace manually since you are overriding the default implementation

Comment: I solved my problem by reconfiguring routes in rails controller. That wasn't ember related. My bad.